# Why is Excel 2016 shrinking text when printing?

Tags: microsoft-excel, printing

This is what the worksheet looks like.

[image]

And this is how it prints.

[image]

As you can see, the text is smaller relative to the width of the column. I checked, and I don't have any scaling, zoom, or fit setting enabled or set to any value. It happens with any printer and to the same degree, so it's not the printer driver.

Is this a known quirk in Excel 2016?

Does anyone know how to calculate in advance how much the shrinkage will be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excel isn't WYSIWYG and Excel isn't about page layout. Printing is a necessary evil for Excel, not something it actually excels at.

There are other metrics more important to Excel printing than whether or not there is white space after data entered in a field.

These will be the fit settings, the page settings, the scaling and borders and selected fields settings.

Excel takes all of these into account, and then when generating the preview and printing, attempts to take each of these into account.

In order to get the layout you want in Excel on the page, you'll have to do quite a bit of trial and error. Thankfully, print preview is reasonably accurate, though even it has some variance, and once the printer gets hold of the page all bets are usually off.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen the same and got used to it. So while text may not fit in a cell in edit view, giving #### (e.g. formatted entries like dates), I'll check what it looks like in the print preview. If it is OK there, I'm happy (that is to say, if the document in question is destinated for printing)

Comment: This doesn't really answer what was asked in the question.

Comment: @fixer1234 yeah, but it's nice to know you're not nuts and that other people have the same issues. :)